# Database authentication failed - "MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed"

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication

I Could n't connect with the MongoDB database.

I was getting this issue when I was trying to connect MongoDB atlas with my Program.

Below source code is used for server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8070;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json);

const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://arunamongo:<password>@cluster0.0sihpzj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } )

.then(() => console.log('Connected Successfully'))

.catch((err) => { console.error(err); });


const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Mongodb connection sucess!");
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0):

```
Check in .env file you have added environment variables like this:
 

    MONGODB_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.0sihpzj.mongodb.net/mydatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority

    Replace username, password, and mydatabase with your actual MongoDB Atlas credentials and database name.
    
    
    Now modify your server.js to use these environment variables:
    
    
   

     const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cors = require('cors');
    require('dotenv').config(); // it load environment variables from .env file
    const app = express();
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8070;
    
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
    
    mongoose.connect(URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
      .then(() => console.log('Connected Successfully'))
      .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });
    
    const connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.once("open", () => {
      console.log("MongoDB connection successful!");
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```